# T-SQL gather same numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2016, concatenation

Hey all I am needing to combine like numbers in my SQL Server 2016 db.

My table structure:

```
--------------------------------
|ID  |number |lastModifiedDate |
--------------------------------
|124 |1      |Mar 27 2018 9:10AM
|124 |2      |Mar 27 2018 9:22AM
|124 |2      |Mar 27 2018 9:22AM
|124 |3      |Mar 27 2018 9:35AM
|124 |4      |Mar 27 2018 9:35AM
|124 |4      |Mar 27 2018 9:38AM
|124 |5      |Mar 27 2018 10:04AM
|124 |5      |Mar 27 2018 10:05AM
```

In the example table above I am looking for the output to look like this (**notice that its showing the latest date/time out of however many same number rows it finds**):

```
|124 |1      |Mar 27 2018 9:10AM
|124 |2      |Mar 27 2018 9:22AM
|124 |3      |Mar 27 2018 9:35AM
|124 |4      |Mar 27 2018 9:38AM
|124 |5      |Mar 27 2018 10:05AM
```

Using this query here:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    CONCAT(number, ' (', lastModifiedDate, ')') AS name
FROM 
    bLine 
WHERE 
    LINK_userTblID = 1 
AND 
    stage = 1
GROUP BY 
    number, id, lastModifiedDate
```

Just outputs the same data as my 1st table example above... **I can only have 2 output column names - that being ID and name**.

I've tried using **distinct** on number but that does not seem to work.

Help would be great to solve my issue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option

```
Select Top 1 with Ties 
       ID
      ,Name = CONCAT(number, ' (', lastModifiedDate, ')')
 From  bLine
 Where LINK_userTblID = 1 and  stage = 1
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,number Order by lastModifiedDate Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name
124 1 (Mar 27 2018  9:10AM)
124 2 (Mar 27 2018  9:22AM)
124 3 (Mar 27 2018  9:35AM)
124 4 (Mar 27 2018  9:38AM)
124 5 (Mar 27 2018 10:05AM)
```

> Updated for comment

```
Select Top 1 with Ties 
       ID
      ,number
      ,lastModifiedDate
 From  bLine
 Where LINK_userTblID = 1 and  stage = 1
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,number Order by lastModifiedDate Desc)
```

Comment: This produces the same output as in my OP.

Comment: :( still resolts in the same out out as examples,

Comment: @StealthRT Clearly the four of us are missing something.  I would suggest that you edit the question and supply the actual desired results

Comment: Seems I got it doing ORDER BY **number Order by lastModifiedDatc**?

Comment: @StealthRT Well done!  Not sure what 8 position means  :)

Comment: Yeah don't know what I was doing there. It should be **Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By number Order by lastModifiedDate Desc)**

Comment: @StealthRT Ah!  I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, number, max(lastmodifieddate)lastmodifieddate
from yourtable
group by  id, number
order by number
```

Comment: If you can only have two columns, just write this to a temp table  or table variable and concatenate after

Comment: This produces the same output as in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two output columns and append the timestamp to the number, you can do this:

```
;with cte AS (
SELECT id, 
number, 
MAX(lastmodifieddate) AS mod_date
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id, number
)

SELECT id, 
CAST(number AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + CAST(mod_date AS VARCHAR(50)) AS new_col
FROM cte
```

Comment: This produces the same output as in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your query to be:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(number, ' (', MAX(lastModifiedDate), ')') AS name
FROM bLine 
WHERE LINK_userTblID = 1 AND  stage = 1
GROUP BY number, id;
```

The important point is that `lastModifiedDate` should not be in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Instead, it should be the argument to an aggregation function.

Also, you probably want to use `CONVERT()` or `FORMAT()` to convert the date to a string, rather than relying on default parameters.

Comment: This produces the same output as in my OP.